# log4j 2.16.0 update issue with offline Maven repo

Tags: maven, log4j

Our build server does not have access to the Maven central repositories.

When updating dependencies I typically create a backup of my repository and then do a diff, and copy the new dependencies to the build machine.

When updating my Log4j dependency to deal with the recent vulnerability this process seems to have broken down.

My dependency on log4j comes from:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I set the log4j version property as such:

```xml
    <properties>
        <log4j2.version>2.16.0</log4j2.version>
    </properties>
```

It builds fine on my machine. And I found the following new files in my local Maven repository which I copied to the Maven repository on the build machine.
[image]

But when the build runs on the build machine, it appears to go hunting for the new version of Log4j in the remote repository and fails as such:

```
161 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
162 Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/logging-parent/3/logging-parent-3.pom
163 [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
164 [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-bom:2.16.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.logging:logging-parent:pom:3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/logging-parent/3/logging-parent-3.pom @ org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-bom:2.16.0, C:\Users\gitlab-runner.ate\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-bom\2.16.0\log4j-bom-2.16.0.pom, line 19, column 11
```

Comment: The error complains about `org.apache.logging:logging-parent:pom:3` being missing. Have you copied that as well? Note that it does not include the name `log4j` in the group ID, so maybe due to that you overlooked it by accident.

Comment: Do you use a repository manager?

Comment: @khmarbaise - you mean something like JFrog Artifactory ? No ...we probably should, but I haven't figured out how to get the permissions to set something like that up

Comment: @Marcono that was it! Thanks - it must have snuck its way into my local repository at somepoint so it didn't come up in my diff snapshot as a new dependency to copy over in my weaksauce manual repository management process.

Comment: Just use a Nexus OSS for example is usually easier to setup.

Comment: A repository mirroring maven central reachable from your build server may be a good idea.